# How to lower screen brightness on a Windows 10 Desktop

Tags: windows, windows-10, display, brightness, gamma

How do I adjust screen brightness in my Windows 10 PC? I have tried to just go into the power settings but there is no slider there as it is supposed to be, and not in the notification icon as it is supposed to be. I cannot remember where else I have checked (I remember some gamma thing that was not there) but I enabled some option called `Enable adaptive brightness`.

How can i change my screen brightness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on a laptop, you can:

- In your taskbar in the bottom right, click `Show Hidden Icons`, then click the `Battery Icon`, then click the `Brightness Percent Button`
- Hold down your `Function Key`, then press `F8` and `F9` to decrease and increase your brightness respectively
- If neither of the above options work for you, you may need to reinstall your display drivers and check if that solves the problem

If you are on a desktop, you need to:

- Use the physical buttons on your monitor to change brightness levels

Comment: there also may be vendor-specific brightness controls that overlay the F keys

Comment: How Would I Use The Buttons to Change The Brightness? I Think i got a packardbell Viseo223DX Screen.

Comment: @sladet If you still have the manual/user guide for that specific screen, it should have step by step directions for that specific model. Other than that, all I can say is try to find a `Menu Button`, then try and use either any `Arrow Buttons` or the `Volume Buttons` to navigate to the display/brightness settings, and adjust them to how you need.

Comment: Found a manual online. https://www.manualslib.com/manual/700978/Packard-Bell-Viseo223dx.html?page=19#manual.                                                                                                 Maneged to fix it! Ty