# How to change desktop PC screen brightness without press the monitor's buttons?

Tags: windows-10, desktop, brightness

There is a post here that seems to be the same question, **but it isn't**!
[How to lower screen brightness on a Windows 10 Desktop](https://superuser.com/questions/1179929/how-to-lower-screen-brightness-on-a-windows-10-desktop)
This is the answer for a laptop, my PC is desktop. It have no battery.

**I don't want to press the monitor's brightness button**. The button work fine, but the monitor's stand is very weak, pressing the button at everyday morning & night cause loosing VGA cable => lost green color in my monitor. I must hit my monitor to get the green back.

**'Radeon Setting' color is horrible.** What ever setting (brightness, temperature, contrast), many objects in the screen become harder to see.

***Is there another way** to change the screen brightness?*

My specs: Windows 10 1809, GPU: Radeon Vega8.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used [ClickMonitorDDC](http://clickmonitorddc.bplaced.net/) to adjust the brightness without resorting to the buttons on the monitor.

Comment: http://clickmonitorddc.bplaced.net/ 404

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Twinkle Tray**

https://github.com/xanderfrangos/twinkle-tray

run on powershell `winget install twinkletray`

It is also available on the Microsoft App Store.

Answer (score 0):

Using PC Settings, Display, you can Enable `Night light`.

[image]
[image]

It will by default refuse to start before 9PM, but you may click
`Night light settings` and click on `Turn on now`.

If you’d rather set your own times, then select the option “Set Hours.” Choose your own times from the drop-down menus under “Turn on” and “Turn off.”

[image]

You may also here set the color temperature at night to your liking.

[image]

For more information see
[Windows 10: Turn On or Off Night Light in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/73518-turn-off-night-light-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: This is good but do no gain the same effect as screen brightness. Anyway, thank you very much.